# how does consul work with redshift?

Tags: docker, jhipster, consul, service-discovery, redhat-containers

We have a spring boot microservice project generated by jhipster. Jhipster built integrated consul for us, and we haven't really touched it since then. 
We are moving to a new deployment with RedShift, which should handle service discovery and other tasks which consul was doing, but all of our services are still dependent on consul.

Is it possible for consul and redshift to play nice? Does one interfere with the other? It seems to me that consul would bottleneck all traffic, but I can't find any sources suggesting that they are competing techs. If there is a conflict, can we refactor the consul integration to work with redshift instead?

Comment: Are you talking about AWS Redshift or Red Hat Openshift ? If it is the former I don't see the connection with Consul as it is a managed Database that can be a replacement for MySQL/Postgres, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about AWS Redshift or Red Hat Openshift ? If it is the former I don't see the connection with Consul as it is a managed Database that can be a replacement for MySQL/Postgres, etc.

However for Openshift, it is running Kubernetes under the hood, which is nice as our Kubernetes sub-generator already supports consul microservices and can even help you deploy an HA Consul registry in a statefulset.
An alternative to this consists in switching out consul discovery with [Spring Cloud Kubernetes](https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes) however this break discovery features in development.

Comment: I believe you are correct that it is Openshift rather than Redshift. That said, are you saying that openshift and consul do provide distinct, non-conflicting services, or did you redirect openshift to poll consul rather than the services consul is monitoring?

Comment: I have never used Openshift myself but I operate a Kubernetes cluster at work (which Openshift is based on). Openshift is more concerned with managing the infrastructure but it does contain some service discovery features (through kube-dns) that could be substituted to consul. However you can deploy an Eureka or Consul registry to it with no problem.